# что означает dot и transpose?

Tags: python, numpy

В общем есть 
`a=[Xsvk,Ysvk,Zsvk]` где **Xsvk,Ysvk,Zsvk** какие-то значения

и есть матрица **b** размера **3x3**

**Функция:**

```
dot(a, transpose(b))
```

**transpose(b)** - я так понимаю транспонирование матрицы **b**?

а в моем случае функция **dot** умножает строку на матрицу?

или столбец на матрицу?

Comment: 1) Да, транспонирование. 2) Строку на матрицу.

Comment: @kff спасибо большое!